# Linear combination and Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Vector of differences. Suppose $x$ is an $n$ -vector. The associated vector of differences is the
$(n-1)$ -vector $d$ given by $d=\left(x_{2}-x_{1}, x_{3}-x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}-x_{n-1}\right) .$ Express $d$ in terms of $x$
using vector operations $(e . g .,$ slicing notation, sum, difference, linear combinations, inner
product). The difference vector has a simple interpretation when $x$ represents a time
series. For example, if $x$ gives the daily value of some quantity, $d$ gives the day-to-day changes in the quantity.

Can any body tell  me what we need to explain here d is just $n-1 \times 1$  vector we want to express d as certain combination  right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your question is at the boundary of maths and programming*

Anyhow, in Python I would write

```
d = x[1:] - x[:-1]
```